# Python except error

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
hours = input("Enter Hours:")

try:
   value = float(hours)
    print value
except:    
    print "Please enter a number"
```

Error:

```
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Comment: It is.............................

Comment: copy entire code file. The error is entirely different than the snippet here.

Comment: I agree, we expect a traceback. But the code is there.

Answer (score 3):

`input` tries to interpret what you provided. Use `raw_input`.

Comment: Thats quite a far sighted answer.

Comment: Once you've encountered this problem, you'll notice it from a mile away...

Comment: Thanks man but it won't work too with the raw_input

Comment: hours = float(raw_input("Enter Hours:"))



try:
   print hours
except:
   print "Please enter a number"